# Redis Queue for Laravel always get filled up

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, predis

I am trying to debug a bug where the application is sending the SMS twice than it supposed to. I am suspecting, it is something to do with the Queue.

Now, everytime I cleared my queue on Redis, it get fills up again with old jobs. I cleared everything in failed_jobs table, but it still happens.

Where all these queued jobs are possibly coming from besides the failed_jobs table?

Comment: check your code

Comment: @ChadidiAbdellah I don't think its coming from the code. Because, all is old jobs

Comment: first stop your Command which normally execute jobs (eg: `php artisan queue:listen` or `queue:work`) because, if you have failed jobs, it adding up again and again to re-attempt the job. So 1st stop execution, then clear the table

Comment: Check your Job classes. Possibly they crash after the SMS has been sent successfully. Any error at any time will cause the job to 'fail'.